Login failed from an untrusted domain using integrated authentication when connecting Excel-Pivot to SQL Server
Situation: I have two SQL Servers with two databases located in the same domain as my client's PC. I'm trying to create two pivot tables using the table relationships in these databases on both servers. They support Windows authentication.
Problem: I can only create the pivot table with the first server. With the second server, Excel gives me the error message:

Login failed. The login is from an untrusted domain and cannot be used with integrated authentication.

I tried to figure out the reason why both servers still behave differently.
According to the SQL Server administration, both SQL Servers are "identically" configured. But I suppose the error is on the Windows system level.
This is how I started the connection:
Step 1

Step 2

The event log on the Windows server, from which I get the login error message, shows the error event:

SSPI handshake failed with error code 0x80090346, state 45 while establishing a connection with integrated security; the connection has been closed. Reason: The Channel Bindings from this client do not match the established Transport Layer Security (TLS) Channel. The service might be under attack, or the data provider might need to be upgraded to support Extended Protection. Closing the connection. Client's supplied SSPI channel bindings were incorrect.

This error event is missing on the server, to which I can connect from Excel.
How can I fix it? I found a related question Extended Protection and SSL Encryption
but it does not really help me.

What is the full output of SELECT @@VERSION when executed against both SQL Servers?

Microsoft SQL Server 2019 (RTM-CU26) (KB5035123). As I said, both SQL servers are configured the same. I suppose the error is on the Windows system level, not on the SQL Server level.

The full output of SELECT @@VERSION includes the host operating system version and patch levels as well, which is why I asked for it. Good luck!

The remaining info was 15.0.4365.2 (X64) Windows Server 2019 10.0  Build 17763 (Hypervisor).
